# PHP page not being displayed error 500

Tags: php

I'm trying to make a website by using `PHP` and when I run it, it comes back `The sharedweb.uniwebsite.ac.uk page isn't working     sharedweb.uniwebsite.ac.uk is currently unable to handle this request. 500` And when I click on the `Details` tab, I get `Press the reload button to resubmit the data needed to load the page.` Which I have done. The previous pages do work and I'm trying to work on the login page and when I go `Register` button, that's when I get the error

**EDIT**

The code that's causing the error is

```
<?php

  // include function files for this application
  require_once('bookmark_fns.php');

  //create short variable names
  $email=$_POST['email'];
  $username=$_POST['username'];
  $passwd=$_POST['passwd'];
  $passwd2=$_POST['passwd2'];
  // start session which may be needed later
  // start it now because it must go before headers
  session_start();
  try   {
    // check forms filled in
    if (!filled_out($_POST)) {
      throw new Exception('You have not filled the form out correctly. Please go back and try again.');
    }

    // email address not valid
    if (!valid_email($email)) {
      throw new Exception('That is not a valid email address.  Please go back and try again.');
    }

    // passwords not the same
    if ($passwd != $passwd2) {
      throw new Exception('The passwords you entered do not match. Please go back and try again.');
    }

    // check password length is ok
    // ok if username truncates, but passwords will get
    // munged if they are too long.
    if (!preg_match('/^(?=.*\d)(?=.*[A-Za-z])[0-9A-Za-z]{6,12}$/)', $passwd)) {
        throw new Exception('Your password must be between 6 and 12 characters inclusive. Please go back and try again.');
    }

    // attempt to register
    // this function can also throw an exception
    register($username, $email, $passwd);
    // register session variable
    $_SESSION['valid_user'] = $username;

    // provide link to members page
    do_html_header('Registration successful');
    echo "Welcome " $_POST["username"];
    echo 'Your registration was successful.  Go to the members page to start setting up your bookmarks!';
    do_html_url('member.php', 'Go to members page');

   // end page
   do_html_footer();
  }
  catch (Exception $e) {
     do_html_header('Warning:');
     echo $e->getMessage();
     do_html_footer();
     exit;
  }
?>
```

**EDIT #2**

It's still not working

Comment: What's the code you are using on your PHP page? Are you sure the web server is running PHP?

Comment: It sounds like there is some kind of error with your server. Have you contacted your hosting company?

Comment: @JamesPaterson The webserver can run php as it ran it and as soon as I clicked on the register button, it gave the error

Comment: What's the code you are using on your PHP page?

Comment: @rontornambe The uni is the hosting company and it has worked before

Comment: @JamesPaterson I've just added it

Comment: What are `do_html_header( )` &  `do_html_url( )` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is an PHP error somewhere. To show the error add the following lines at the top of your script:

```
error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set("display_errors", 1);
```

(remove them after fixing the error, to not expose any secrets later)

Possibility 2 would be to check your error.log, which will tell you why its not working too.

Comment: It's not showing any errors. It's still showing the same thing

Comment: Are you sure that its really on the page that shows the error 500?

Comment: I put that at the top of the script and didn't show the errors that was causing the problem. How would I do an error log?